# How to use sculpting tools from a 90 degree angle?

Tags: sculpting, workflow, sculpt-mode

Given the sphere pictured here, I switch into Sculpt Mode and use the Grab Tool. I want to grab at the exact maximum of the the right side of the sphere. If I were able to do this, the yellow circle should appear to be straight vertical line representing 90 degrees. However, my best attempt is pictured and I would estimate this to be ~75 degrees.

**Is there a setting that would allow for this maximum angle (90deg) to be accessed?** The use-case for this seems practical enough when trying to sculpt something without it becoming lopsided. I think symmetry settings are kind of a workaround for this, but it would be nice to not need them.

[image: Sculpting a sphere with grab brush at angle]

Comment: As a work around I usually open a new 3D viewer to work from another point of view. I can see the result of my action in my first point of view.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workflow. This is what I was hoping to avoid, switching to so many different views to "even out" a sculpt. If I were to execute the pictured grab, subsequently I would need to switch to top view, observe that I've lopsided the sphere forward, and compensate with another grab. Repeat.

It's annoying not having a way to grab outwards perfectly. I suppose I could switch to edit mode and pull the vertex outwards with proportional editing, but still an inconvenience.

Comment: Have you tried setting the falloff of the brush to projected instead of the default sphere?

Comment: @Vagabonk amazing! Setting <kbd>n</kbd> menu > Tool > Brush Settings > Falloff > Falloff Shape to projected pulls the side evenly. Mind adding this as an official answer? Would love to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Setting <kbd>n</kbd> menu > Tool > Brush Settings > Falloff > Falloff Shape to projected pulls the side evenly.

Answer (score -4):

Well, you could use it from a side view, etc orthrographic. If necessary,make a background image with the angle available to view so you can line it up.

You could use a custom brush.

Or you could just use a boolean and rotate it to the exact degrees you want and apply it.